# Expressing two probability measures as an integral over their average.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I've been given the following statement without proof and have been struggling to prove it myself:

Given two probability measures $\mathbf{P}_1$ and $\mathbf{P}_2$ there exists a probability measure $\nu$ as well as measurable functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}_1(A) = \int_A f_0 d\nu \textrm{ and }
\mathbf{P}_2(A) = \int_A f_1 d\nu
\end{equation*}

It has also been stated that this claim can be proven using measure theory for $\nu = \frac{\mathbf{P}_1+\mathbf{P}_2}{2}$.

At first I thought that the claim can be proven trivially using Fubini's theorem, however I somehow couldn't get the form we need.

It has also been stated that in the case when $\mathbf P_1$ and $\mathbf P_2$ have probability densities $g_1$ and $g_2$ (for probability measures on the Borel algebra of $\mathbb R$) for any probability measure $\nu$ with probability density $g$ we get $f_i=\frac{g_i}{g}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Radon-Nikodým theorem, which is applicable since both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice proof using Hilbert space theory. The functional $\phi : L^2((P_1 + P_2)/2) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $$\phi(g) = \int g \,dP_1$$ is easily verified to be continuous by use of Cauchy Schwarz inequality. By Hilbert space theory, there exists $f \in L^2((P_1 + P_2)/2)$ such that for all $g \in L^2((P_1 + P_2)/2)$, $$\int g \,dP_1 = \int gf \,d\nu.$$
Since indicators $g = 1_A$ are in $L^2$, we are done.